# Fulltext search replacement Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to implement a search functionnality with autocomplete in a project I'm working on. So far I've managed to do this with a select column1, column2 where myColumn like %...% but it isn't as responsive is I would like, I mean it's just ok and it searches only in one single row. The current version of MySql with innoDB tables doesn't support "match against" any plans on upgrading the db version? Otherwise, could anyone suggest another way of achieving a search + autocomp (against a single table).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try www.rockitsearch.com , it has the autocomplete implementation. The only thing you'll need to do is : 
- create an account
- export your data

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but if I ever wanted to use a search service, google already offers a search API.